# How can I tell which static IP address one computer uses to connect to another computer?

Tags: ip, unix, static-ip, static-routes

I have a workstation connected to several internal networks, with a different static IP address on each of them. Through one (?) of these networks, I can connect to a server over ssh. How can I tell which of my workstation's IP addresses is used to connect to the server? There's no NAT between the two computers as far as I can tell.

Comment: Run netstat and look for the foreign address of the server. When you find it look at the local address to determine which local address is connecting to the server.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On a Linux machine you can find the source IP that will be used for a connection with `ip route get $destination_ip`

This is the primary IP of the interface that is directly connected with the next hop.

Answer (score 1):

Via `ssh`?

```
server$ echo $SSH_CLIENT
1234:5678:90a:bc::805f:c436 58642 22
server$
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use traceroute and see from which IP it goes. Or after ssh'ing to the server check:

```
who am i
```

the last field is your IP or fqdn if it has a reverse DNS entry.

Another option is, after ssh'ing to your server, do a :

```
tcpdump -nnpi any icmp
```

And from another terminal from your workstation ping that host. You'll see in the tcpdump shell icmp packets from your workstation's IP

Now that i think about it, you dont even need access to the server, you can launch tcpdump on your host checking for packets for a choosen unused port, let's say 121345, on one root shell in your workstation:

```
tcpdump -nnpi any port 12345
```

Then from a normal terminal window on your workstation:

```
telnet server 12345
```

or:

```
nc server 12345
```

On the tcpdump shell you'll see the IP you're using to connect to the server.

Comment: I already know my fqdn; is there a way to get `who` to return my IP address?

Comment: from who's manual page it seems not. But you can just resolve what who says (assuming your DNS is correct) whith host YOUR_FQDN. It will resolve in one IP.
Alternatively you can grep for your username on /var/log/secure (in redhat at least). I updated my answer with yet another way to get your IP

Answer (score 0):

If you're on Windows, use `tracert <destination IP>` from your source computer to find the route it's traversing to the destination.

Comment: OSX and Linux, but this is still good to know.

Comment: A network may be designed in such a way that you don't get correct information from this. For instance, in a network which uses MPLS, by default, the routers will not show up in the trace.

Comment: Some firewalls (e.g. Cisco PIX/ASA) won't show up by default, either.

Comment: @Dan, sorry, I missed your tag above.
Thank you to the others as well-- it's good to know the possible gotchas involved in this one.